# Why is Anaconda installer failing on CentOS?

Tags: anaconda, installation, tar, md5sum

I downloaded and ran the Anaconda interactive installer Anaconda3-2020.02-Linux-x86_64.sh but it fails right after it asks for the installation path with this:

```
PREFIX=/home/msimenc/software/anaconda3
WARNING: md5sum mismatch of tar archive
expected: 826b70d8ad34b7d9230d4da350d1b598
     got: a8697164e5fc3778465b66505a311356  -
Unpacking payload ...
/home/msimenc/software/anaconda3/conda.exe: line 1: https://www.anaconda.com/pycharm\n: No such file or directory

/home/msimenc/software/anaconda3/conda.exe: line 3: syntax error near unexpected token `fi'
/home/msimenc/software/anaconda3/conda.exe: line 3: `fi'
/home/msimenc/software/anaconda3/conda.exe: line 1: https://www.anaconda.com/pycharm\n: No such file or directory

/home/msimenc/software/anaconda3/conda.exe: line 3: syntax error near unexpected token `fi'
/home/msimenc/software/anaconda3/conda.exe: line 3: `fi'ls
```

Any ideas?

Comment: How did you download the installer?

Comment: I realized I actually downloaded an old installer linked to from a website. This time I downloaded from: https://repo.anaconda.com/archive/Anaconda3-2020.02-Linux-x86_64.sh. I updated my post with the error, different this time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out downloading the installer failed. Re-downloaded it and it works fine.